How to render specific pages (not entire PDF file) using react-pdf?
I am working on a React project for displaying pdf file as a flipbook using Nextjs and react-pageflip.
'use client'

import { useResizeObserver } from '@wojtekmaj/react-hooks'
import {
  ForwardedRef,
  forwardRef,
  ReactNode,
  useCallback,
  useState,
} from 'react'
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf'
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css'
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/TextLayer.css'
import '../../polyfills.mjs'

import type { PDFDocumentProxy } from 'pdfjs-dist'
import HTMLFlipBook from 'react-pageflip'

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
  'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.mjs',
  import.meta.url
).toString()

const options = {
  cMapUrl: '/cmaps/',
  standardFontDataUrl: '/standard_fonts/',
}

const resizeObserverOptions = {}

const maxWidth = 800

type PDFFile = string | File | null

interface PagesProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

const Pages = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, PagesProps>(
  ({ children }, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    return (
      <div className="bg-white" ref={ref}>
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }
)

Pages.displayName = 'Pages'

export default function FlipBook() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState<PDFFile>('./leart-profile.pdf')
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState<number>()
  const [containerRef, setContainerRef] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null)
  const [containerWidth, setContainerWidth] = useState<number>()

  const onResize = useCallback<ResizeObserverCallback>((entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries

    if (entry) {
      setContainerWidth(entry.contentRect.width)
    }
  }, [])

  useResizeObserver(containerRef, resizeObserverOptions, onResize)

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({
    numPages: nextNumPages,
  }: PDFDocumentProxy): void {
    setNumPages(nextNumPages)
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen overflow-hidden bg-gray-900 md:justify-center scroll-mx-2">
      <div
        className="w-full max-w-[calc(100%-2em)] m-[1em_0]"
        ref={setContainerRef}
      >
        {/* @ts-expect-error ignore HTMLFlipBook types */}
        <HTMLFlipBook
          width={750}
          height={420}
          className="z-50"
          showCover={true}
          maxShadowOpacity={0.35}
        >
          {Array.from(new Array(numPages), (_el, index) => (
            <Pages key={`page_${index + 1}`}>
              <Document
                file={file}
                onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                options={options}
                loading={null}
              >
                <Page
                  pageNumber={index + 1}
                  width={
                    containerWidth
                      ? Math.min(containerWidth, maxWidth)
                      : maxWidth
                  }
                />
              </Document>
            </Pages>
          ))}
        </HTMLFlipBook>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


For example: I just need to render the indexed page in the array. i don't want to render all pages.
Is there a way to do this using react-pdf or we need to use another library for this?
I have tried different pdf libraries but they do not have the option to display the specific pages. All of them are displaying the entire PDF file.
What I tried
Tried the mapping function in the Page component. That didn't works with react-flipbook
What I'm expecting
Needs to render just the indexed page of the map
